# Removing the callback from inside the for-each loop

Tags: c#

Here is the code for the most part:

```
foreach (var file in dialog.Files.Where(someConditionsGoHere).AsEnumerable())
{
    Images imageRec = this.CreateNew<Images>();
    imageRec.Description = file.Name;
    imageRec.AsOfDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    // inits some more fields here 

    using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead())
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
        fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        if (imageRec.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIFF" || imageRec.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIF")
        {
            // pop a yes/no dialog to convert to PDF.
            Action<UI.Interactivity.InteractionRequest.YesNoDialog.YesNoDialogConfirmation> callback = c =>
                {
                    if (c.Yes)
                    {
                        foreach (var tiffFile in dialog.Files)
                        {
                            string ext = tiffFile.Extension.Substring(1);
                            if (ext.ToUpper() != "TIF" && ext.ToUpper() != "TIFF") continue;

                            using (System.IO.Stream tiffFileStream = tiffFile.OpenRead())
                            {
                                byte[] tiffFileBytes =
                                    new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(tiffFileStream.Length)];
                                tiffFileStream.Read(tiffFileBytes, 0, tiffFileBytes.Length);

                                Images imageRec2 = this.CreateNew<Images>();
                                imageRec2.Description = tiffFile.Name;
                                imageRec2.Extension = "pdf";
                                // some more inits and sutff here too.
                                ImagingUtilities.ConvertImgToPDF(tiffFileBytes, imageRec2)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);
                    }
                };

            this.OpenYesNoDialog("Do you want to convert Tiff files to PDF before saving them?", callback);

        }
        else
        {
            this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Currently it is showing the `YesNo dialog` while looping through the images in and if that image is a `".tiff"` file it goes to the `callback` method with `YesNo` dialog asking if user wants to convert that to `PDF` instead.
The problem is I don't want it to ask the user for each `tiff` file, I want it to ask only once, so I should take out that `callback` from the `for-each loop` but when I do that I lose the order in which commands are getting called because of the `async` attribute of the callback.  Can someone help with restructuring this?

Comment: You see the `if (c.Yes)`? Do you think that could be a variable you introduce?

Comment: You could always do two loops. The first to find out if there is a `.tiff` file then prompt the `YesNo` dialog. then use the second to convert the files.

Comment: @CodeCaster yes I can keep the answer to c.Yes in a variable, if that was your question.

Comment: @DavidL The code is not behaving as desired. It isn't working code that the OP wants to refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without any re-writing really, and just moving code around, you can do this:

```
//any additional logic like filtering for if we have a tiff etc here.

    Action<UI.Interactivity.InteractionRequest.YesNoDialog.YesNoDialogConfirmation> callback = c =>
            {
                if (c.Yes)
                {
                    foreach (var tiffFile in dialog.Files.Where(x=>x.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIFF" || x.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIF"))
                    {


                        using (System.IO.Stream tiffFileStream = tiffFile.OpenRead())
                        {
                            byte[] tiffFileBytes =
                                new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(tiffFileStream.Length)];
                            tiffFileStream.Read(tiffFileBytes, 0, tiffFileBytes.Length);

                            Images imageRec2 = this.CreateNew<Images>();
                            imageRec2.Description = tiffFile.Name;
                            imageRec2.Extension = "pdf";
                            // some more inits and sutff here too.
                            ImagingUtilities.ConvertImgToPDF(tiffFileBytes, imageRec2)
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);
                }
            };

        this.OpenYesNoDialog("Do you want to convert Tiff files to PDF before saving them?", callback);


    //tiff already handled
    foreach (var file in dialog.Files.Where(x=>x.Conditions&& !x.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIFF" && !x.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIF").AsEnumerable())
    {
        Images imageRec = this.CreateNew<Images>();
        imageRec.Description = file.Name;
        imageRec.AsOfDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        // inits some more fields here 

        using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
            fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);


            this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hmm, it still asked the Tiff to PDF convert question even if the images I select are not Tiff

Comment: Yes. It will, I didn't add any additional logic, I just moved the callback so its called once.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it, just added a boolean to see if we have selected any tiffs, if yes then call the this.OpenYesNoDialog, otherwise nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an outermost loop that iterates over `dialog.Files`, and then another one inside the callback that iterates over `dialog.Files`. This is one too many levels of iteration.

I think you can fix this by breaking this up into a few methods. Write a method `ProcessFile` that takes a single `File` object, and a bool representing whether or not it needs to be converted to PDF (or whatever it is you're doing differently inside your callback), and processes it accordingly.

Now you can replace all of the code you've pasted here with the following:

```
this.OpenYesNoDialog("...", ans => {
    foreach(var file in dialog.Files.Where(someConditionsGoHere))
        ProcessFile(file, ans.Yes)
});
```

Here is what I think `ProcessFile` should look like based on my limited understanding of your code:

```
private void ProcessFile(File file, bool convertToPDF) 
{
    Images imageRec = this.CreateNew<Images>();

    imageRec.Description = file.Name;
    imageRec.AsOfDate = System.DateTime.Now;
    // ...

    using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead()) {
        byte[] fileBytes = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
        fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

        if (convertToPDF && (ext.ToUpper() == "TIF" || ext.ToUpper() == "TIFF")) 
        {
            // Configure imageRec fields for PDF
            imageRec.Extension = "pdf";
            // ...

            ImagingUtilities.ConvertImgToPDF(tiffFileBytes, imageRec);
        }
        else
        {
            // Configure imageRec fields for everything else
            // ...

            this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will restructure it the way you suggest and see how it behaves.

Comment: @Bohn I've provided an implementation of `ProcessFile` that I think should work.

Answer (score 1):

Rough and tough for what you pasted. You need some changes to the pdf ConvertImgToPDF call to return a byte array. This removes the double loop and only prompts once for the tiffs.

```
   var askedToConvert = false;
   var convertTiff = false;
   foreach (var file in dialog.Files.Where(someConditionsGoHere).AsEnumerable())
    {
        Images imageRec = this.CreateNew<Images>();
        imageRec.Description = file.Name;
        imageRec.AsOfDate = System.DateTime.Now;
        // inits some more fields here 


        using (System.IO.Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead())
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[System.Convert.ToInt32(fileStream.Length)];
            fileStream.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);

            if (imageRec.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIFF" || imageRec.Extension.ToUpper() == "TIF")
            {

                 if(!askedToConvert) 
                 {          
                     this.OpenYesNoDialog("Do you want to convert Tiff files to PDF before saving them?", c=>  {
                       askedToConvert = true;
                       convertTiff = c.Yes;
                     });
                 }
                 if(convertTiff) 
                 {          

                     imageRec.Extension = "pdf";
                     // some more inits and sutff here too.             
                     fileBytes = ImagingUtilities.ConvertImgToPDF(fileBytes) ; // this needs to return new bytes    

              } 

              this.SaveAndAddImage(imageRec, fileBytes, file.Name);

        }
    }
```

Comment: is there a reason var askedToConvert = false;
        var convertTiff = false;  are inside the for-each and not out of it? Thanks.

Comment: @Bohn Good catch, yes they should be outside.